# Calling another contract's function fails for no apparent reason

Tags: solidity, remix, error

I have this piece of code in Remix-IDE + Metamask, both at the most recent versions (but I also tried without Remix-IDE):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Foo {
    bool public lastVal = false;

    function fooFunc(bool x) public returns (bool) {
        lastVal = x;
        return !x;
    }
}

contract Bar {
    bool public barBool = false;
    Foo myFoo;

    function Bar(address _myFooAddr) public {
        myFoo = Foo(_myFooAddr);
    }

    function barFunc() public {
        barBool = myFoo.fooFunc(barBool);
    }
}
```

Whenever I call barFunc() Remix-IDE refuses to run it because it says that the transaction will surely fail. If I force to run the transaction, it actually fails with a REVERT.

Anyway, I don't see any apparent reasons as to why this should fail.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This code works fine for me. Make sure you're putting the right address in for your deployed `Foo` contract, and be sure to enclose the address in double quotes.

Comment: Yep, the reason was that Remix-IDE wants address in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy-pasted your code to remix and chose JavaScripit VM to check if code is ok. First initialized Foo contract and then Bar contract providing Foo instance address as argument to constructor and everything is working for me as it should (at least from my understanding).
So the code itself is not a problem. There may be smth wrong with communication between remix and MetaMask maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I finally got the reason why. In Remix-IDE you must use quation marks when passing an address to a function. Now it works. I got confused also because static analysis was highlighting that barFunc() was having an infinite cost. I hope this will help others.